# Tracking particles with ImageFeatureTrack

Tags: image-processing, tracking

I am currently trying to track little dots in a series of the following images:

[image: particles]

However, some of the dots disappear and reappear all the time. As soon as a dot is not linked by `ImageFeatureTrack`, no new track is generated at a later time, so eventually no tracks remain.

I am able to write a more sophisticated tracking algorithm, but before I do that I was wondering if one can modify `ImageFeatureTrack` to not only track particles visible in the first image, but also new ones that might appear later.

Comment: i think Mathematica does not have that capability in `ImageFeatureTrack` as of yet. It would be great if they can use some sampling methods to enhance the utility of this function for tracking and linking in general

Comment: Could you start tracking at different times (frame number). You track the particles that are in the first image through and then start with a later frame number when new particles appear and trace those. Could that be an idea.